# How do I find out which spring component is incompatible?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot, gradle

I'm trying to write some junit tests for a project using spring and gradle. I'm getting

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.AutoConfigureReportTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(AutoConfigureReportTestExecutionListener.java:49)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer : org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SharedMetadataReaderFactoryContextInitializer
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:381)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:358)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.initialize(SpringApplication.java:230)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:206)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.getSpringApplication(SpringBootContextLoader.java:121)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SharedMetadataReaderFactoryContextInitializer.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:376)
    ... 32 more
```

I've been told this is likely to be an issue with incompatible spring components. These are the ones in my gradle.properties

```
SpringSecurityConfig = 4.0.2.RELEASE
SpringSecurityWeb = 4.0.2.RELEASE
SpringWeb = 4.3.6.RELEASE
SpringWebMVC = 4.3.6.RELEASE
SpringBootTestAutoConfigure = 1.4.0.RELEASE
SpringSecurityTest = 4.0.2.RELEASE
SpringContextVersion = 4.1.7.RELEASE
SpringTestVersion = 4.3.6.RELEASE
SpringBootTestVersion = 1.2.5.RELEASE
SpringBootStarterVersion = 1.2.5.RELEASE
SpringDataRedisVersion = 1.6.4.RELEASE
SpringRetryVersion = 1.2.0.RELEASE
SpringDataJpaVersion = 1.8.0.RELEASE
```

How do I figure out which of these is incompatible?

Comment: The moment you use Spring dependencies in different versions: 4.0.2 , 4.3.6, 4.1.7, you cannot expect that all components should integrate seamlessly.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza The versions are different because Spring Boot, Spring Core and Spring Security are not version-aligned, e.g. Spring Boot 1.2.5 depends on Spring Core 4.1.7

Comment: Try to get SpringBoot* versions to align.

Comment: Never mix versions of a framework. You are mixing spring boot 1.2.5 and 1.4.0 never do that. Spring Boot manages all other versions and mixing Spring Boot versions will also lead to mixing Spring and Spring Security versions leading to incompatible versions. So in short fix your spring boot versions (you should remove the versions and only use the one from the parent Spring Boot will manage the others) and everything else will align (assuming you don't have explicit version numbers there).

Comment: I see. Let's say I've changed SpringBootStarterVersion to 1.4.0. How do I get gradle to download the files for the new version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run

`gradle dependencies --configuration compile`

The output shows where versions have been changed, e.g. `spring-beans:4.1.6.RELEASE -> 4.1.7.RELEASE` because `spring-security-web` 4.0.2 wants `spring-beans` 4.1.6, but `spring-boot-starter` 1.2.5 wants `spring-core` 4.1.7

Likely conflict contender is:

```
SpringBootTestAutoConfigure = 1.4.0.RELEASE
    depends on spring-boot:1.4.0.RELEASE and spring-core:4.3.2.RELEASE
SpringBootStarterVersion = 1.2.5.RELEASE
    depends on spring-boot:1.2.5.RELEASE and spring-core:4.1.7.RELEASE
```

Comment: @achAmháin What makes you think they are using Grails? There is no mention of Grails in the question.

Comment: I see. Let's say I've changed SpringBootStarterVersion to 1.4.0. How do I get gradle to download the files for the new version?

Comment: @Lifus That happens automatically when you use Gradle. It's what it does.

Comment: I've changed the SpringBootStarterVersion to 1.4.0, but when I try to run the junit test it still fails. I've tried gradle --refresh-dependencies and refresh gradle project through eclipse but it still fails.

Comment: @Lifus It still fails with the same `NoSuchMethodException`?

Comment: Nevermind, I also had to update SpringBootTestVersion. Everything works now, thank you very much!